# Remove outer component tag from html in angular 7

Tags: angular

Similar questions have been asked and usually people suggest a change in the component selector.

In my case, is doesn't work.

Here's the scenario:

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)'s [Expansion panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) an I want to have a component for each individual item in the panel:

```js
@Component({
  selector: '[app-panel-item]',
  templateUrl: './panel-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-item.component.scss']
})
export class PanelItemComponent
```

```html
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      Title
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      desc
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
     BODY
  <mat-action-row>
    <button mat-raised-button>Button</button>
  </mat-action-row>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

The issue is that, using either `<app-panel-item>` or `<div app-panel-item>` creates an outer html tag that messes up the styling.
I tried removing `<mat-expansion-panel>` from the directive and using `<mat-expansion-panel app-panel-item>` but you can't have 2 structural selectors together.

Expected layout:

[image: Expected]

Actual result:

[image: Actual]

How can I actually remove that outer tag created by the component?

EDIT: [Stackblitz](https://angular-ok9bzj.stackblitz.io)

Comment: can you provided minimal stackblitz?

Comment: https://angular-ok9bzj.stackblitz.io https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ok9bzj

Comment: Which outer tag are you talking about?

Comment: The app-panel-item wrapping the content of the component. I updated the stackblitz. The first 3 rows has this wrapping tag I mentioned and the last 3 doesn't.

Comment: Still not getting it, your top 3 rows and bottom 3 rows looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem only is border-radius you can add this style into your styles.css

```
.mat-accordion app-panel-item .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expanded), .mat-accordion app-panel-item .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expansion-panel-spacing) {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.mat-accordion app-panel-item:first-of-type .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.mat-accordion app-panel-item:last-of-type .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

here is the example with styles in styles.css

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xmec5

component.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-accordion app-panel-item .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expanded),::ng-deep .mat-accordion app-panel-item .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expansion-panel-spacing) {
    border-radius: 0; 
}

::ng-deep .mat-accordion app-panel-item:first-of-type .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-accordion app-panel-item:last-of-type .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

stackblitz example with ::ng-deep

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-39tbxt

Comment: This will apply globally. I think using `ng::deep` is more appropriate.

Comment: But on the other hand, if he uses the expansion panel with  `PanelItemComponent` component, maybe he needs it globally.

Comment: This is just the way i prefer it. I prefer this due to component and project isolation.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I am not familiar with ng::deep but since it worked I am accepting your answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Saita Thank you too, glat to help. I will put the example with ng::deep too.

Comment: @Saita please chech the second example (`panel-item.component.css`) file